# PageView PageController.jumpPage with StreamBuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here's the code.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Widget>>(
        stream: _getMealsViewWidgets(weekNum),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Widget>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (snapshot.error != null) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error occurred.'));
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return PageView(children: snapshot.data, controller: _pageController);
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
```

The PageView has fix 7 pages. I'd like to jump after a refresh to a specific page. The problem is because the PageView is a return of a StreamBuilder I can't call the pagecontroller.jumpPage method after the refresh. How can I jump to a specific page after return?

Comment: can u explain how u solved this using postframecallback?

Comment: ```if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => {
                  if (_pageController.hasClients) {_pageController.jumpToPage(currentPage)}
                });```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // executes after build
})
```

?